# Call methods (using constructor) from a class extending view

Tags: android, view, constructor, call, extends

I used canvas to draw some bitmaps. Everything fine here, I used a class extending view and using the constructor super(context, attributeset);
Now I want to use methods from another class, but how to get this to work, as far as I know the view extending class needs these two constructors they must be set to work with android (I tried to change it and it tells me that it needs these constructor like this because it extends of view).

This is my code:

```
public class GameBoard extends View{

    private static final String tag = "GameBoard";

    private Paint p;
    private Load load;

    public GameBoard(Context context, Load load) {

            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            this.load = load;
```

//There is a lot more in this class but it doesnt matters here.

```
     }
```

And this is the other class:

```
public class Load{

Context context;
```

// TODO load these infos from files and make the textures fit with phone screen size
    int mSize = 99;
    int tSize = 48;
    int screenCoords = 160;
    int rectX = 10;
    int rectY = 16;

```
String coordsFileName ="coordsData.txt";

public Load (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found an solution for everyone with the same problem.
Just create an object in the extending class for example:
extending class:
//above constructor declare object off the other class

```
private OtherClass otherclass;
```

//and in its contructor you just create an new object

```
this.otherclass = new OtherClass();
```

Comment: Now I want to use methods from another class, but how to get this to work can you be bit more specific ?

Comment: @Triode I want to use for example the method getMapSize which is located at the class load. To use it I need an constructor reffering load, but GameBoard already got an fix constructor because it extends of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no just created an new object of the class I wanted so I don't need to overgive it to the constructor:

```
public class GameBoard extends View{

private static final String tag = "GameBoard";

private Paint p;
private Load load;

public GameBoard(Context context) {

        super(context);
        p = new Paint();
        load = new Load();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your `GameBoard` object not from XML layout, but in the code, then add it to your layout. In this case you can create your constructor and pass the objects you need. You can create a `FrameLayout` in the xml, then add your view to that layout.

Comment: May you give me an example, I didn't added any views from code yet. And don't know why I'm allowed then to leave out the construtor, it does still extends view doesnt it?

Comment: I have created a simple app, where I have passed a String to View object in constructor,So I have modified the constructor of my View. http://db.tt/SGF9Juf1